# Gunicorn worker stuck

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

When I run my docker container, its boots up and gets stuck at:

```
[2020-07-09 11:07:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.10.0

[2020-07-09 11:07:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5002 (1)

[2020-07-09 11:07:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync

[2020-07-09 11:07:45 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
```

This is the same even if I increase timeout.
But once I enter Ctrl+C to exit, it prints the output

```
^C[2020-07-09 11:08:51 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: int
checkpoint1
checkpoint2
checkpoint3
checkpoint4
```

Port mapping are also correct.
Why is this happening? I even tried with different versions of gunicorn and python. But still the same.

My docker cmd:

```
CMD ["gunicorn","-w","1","--timeout","1200","-b","0.0.0.0:5002","autocorrectapi:app"]
```

Comment: what makes you think it's stuck?

Comment: Im not able to figure it out. The exact same thing if I run on my machine it is working.

Comment: It does not look like it is stuck, it looks more like its awaiting connections, try to connect to port 5002 and see if anything shows up in the logs.

Comment: Im not able to connect to the port. It just keeps loading. On checking the port mapping it looks fine. 
0.0.0.0:5002->5002/tcp